# Is there any way to set SendEmailAsync to isHtml= true?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, sendasync

I am working on Forgot Password Functionality in Asp.Net MVC.

I am able to successfully send forgot password link to email thorugh `SendEmailAsync` Method, but email is isHtml = false.

How can I make it to true?

```
public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
{
   SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
   return client.SendMailAsync("email",
                                    message.Destination,
                                    message.Subject,
                                    message.Body);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [another overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes a [`MailMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx) object. For example:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
var message = new MailMessage();
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = "email";
//Set other properties such as subject etc.
return client.SendMailAsync(message);
```

Comment: Is there any way to set expiry for the recovery link I will send with email?

Comment: That's down to your application, nothing to do with the email.